# fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, type-traits, openfst

So I've just started off with Google's OpenFST toolkit and I'm trying out their examples. Using C++ on Eclipse Mars and upon build I get the following error:

`fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found`

Here's my sample program - when I'm trying from [here](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/FstQuickTour#Creating_FSTs_Using_Constructors).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fst/fst-decl.h>
#include <fst/fstlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    fst::StdVectorFst fst; 

    return 0;
}
```

And when I build it, I get the following errors:

```
/usr/local/include/fst/util.h:15:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
#include <type_traits>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/sampleFST.o] Error 1
```

Is there some linker error? Why is it unable to find that header file? It does exist in the `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/` directory on my computer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: gcc 4.2 is a fossil. Upgrade.

Comment: gcc 6.0 is latest?

Comment: 6.3 and 5.4 are current but any 5 or 6 version should do.

Comment: @n.m. I just upgraded my gcc but the error still persists :(

Comment: You probably need to pass -std=c++11 flag to g++.

Comment: I am doing that. I added `-stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++11` but still the error persists :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132427/discussion-between-n-m-and-saturnian).

Answer (score 4):

looks like a C compiler, trying to compile a C++ file

```cpp
// test.h
#include <type_traits>
```

```
clang -c test.h
# test.h:1:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found

gcc -c test.h
# test.h:1:10: fatal error: type_traits: No such file or directory

# solutions ...

# fix file extension
gcc -c test.hh
clang -c test.hh

# set language in compiler flag
gcc -c -x c++ test.h
clang -c -x c++ test.h

# set language in compiler command
g++ -c in.h
clang++ -c in.h
```

the file `type_traits` is provided by package `libstdc++`,
see [debian package search](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=%2Ftype_traits&mode=&suite=bullseye&arch=any)

related: clang throws error `file not found` when a `cppheader.h` file is wrapped in a `wrapper.hpp` file

```
# cppheader.h has wrong file extension, should be hh/hpp/hxx
echo '#include <type_traits>' >cppheader.h
echo '#include "cppheader.h"' >wrapper.hpp

# error with clang
clang -c wrapper.hpp # -> fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found

# works with gcc
gcc -c wrapper.hpp
```

Comment: What?? Why are you answering a 5 year old question? I don't think this is a problem anymore... Plus the answer is wrong, [see the discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132427/discussion-between-n-m-and-saturnian)

Comment: "Your case" is not the answer to this question. It's the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I counted for this problem,solved it in this way:
xxx.c->xxx.cpp
all in all, you should compile it in g++, not gcc

Comment: did not work for me